# Training VGG16 from scratch doesn't improve accuracy in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train VGG16 models using both transfer learning and training from scratch. I have a dataset with 7k images per category, and 4 different categories. I managed to come up with the transfer learning code no problem, however, the same program but for training from scratch does not seem to be working.

creating the model for transfer learning:

```py
base_model = apps.VGG16(
    include_top=False,  # This is if we want the final FC layers
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=input_shape,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
    pooling = pooling,
)

# Freeze the base model
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# convert output of base model to a 1D vector
x = Flatten()(base_model.output)

# We create fc_count fully connected layers, relu for all but the last
x = Dense(units=4096, activation='relu')(x) # relu avoids vanishing gradient problem
x = Dense(units=4096, activation='relu')(x) # relu avoids vanishing gradient problem 

# The final layer is a softmax layer
prediction = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=prediction)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
            metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Meanwhile, for training from scratch:

```py
model = apps.VGG16(
    include_top=True,  # This is if we want the final FC layers
    weights=None,
    input_shape=input_shape,
    classifier_activation="softmax",
    pooling = pooling,
    classes = 4 # set the number of outputs to required count
)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
            optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1), # I've experimented w values as low as 0.001
            metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

and the training is done via

```
history = model.fit(train_images,
                        validation_data=val_images,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        verbose=1, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Transfer learning takes around 10 epochs to converge, whereas I've gone up to 20 epochs when training from scratch, converging to an accuracy and val_accuracy of exactly 0.2637. I have a ReduceLROnPlateau that does make a difference when transfer learning.

I'm training on a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU.

EDIT: I should mention that I am getting loss of nan when training from scratch

Comment: Use a different optimizer: The Adam optimizer is a good choice, but you might want to try a different optimizer, such as SGD or Adagrad, to see if it works better for your specific problem.

Comment: I can't imagine you can train a model of 140_000_000 of parameters in only 20 epochs (without initialize correctly your initial weights and bias) !!! That's why transfer learning exist. If you want to increase the accuracy after transfer learning, unfreeze 2 or 3 blocks of convolution (fine tuning) and fit again to specialize your network to your classes. Try more epochs if you want to start from scratch and use initializers like HeUniform instead of using random weights.

Comment: @Corralien I know I need more epochs for training from scratch... my issue is that there is 0 convergence at all with pretraining - and your solution of attempting transfer learning is not helpful. As I said in the post, I was able to transfer learn VGG16 no problem, but I want to train from scratch which I have not been able to do

Comment: @Marya Thanks for the suggestion. After a few epochs it seems to be doing better. Is there any particular reason as to why SGD would be better for this specific task? as I've used Adam for all my transfer learning without issue

Comment: So try to load the weights and bias from imagenet without freeze the model (so don't use `weights=None`) to start from a potential good state for the gradient descent (at least it can't be worse than random intialization). Let me know if it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved by switching to the SGD optimizer